# transpose 2D Array List using swap or suggest me a way to swap without using additional Array list

Tags: java, arraylist, 2d, transpose, swap

please find the below code for 2D array list swap, have used swap only for normal array list, please let me know how to do it using 2D array list

```
   int n=A.size();
   int m=A.get(0).size();
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
      for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {  
         //i have tried to swap using collections.swap            
          Collections.swap(A,A.get(i).get(j),A.get(j).get(i));
        }
   }
```

Comment: I would avoid using `Collections#swap` entirely (since you're involving different lists), and do the swapping manually yourself. To do so, you'll need to store the value from the first list in a temporary variable, then overwrite the first in-list value with the one from the second list, and then finally write your temporary variable into the second list. This can be done in either direction, you must simply pick one.

Comment: thanks , i have used temp variable and updated the arraylist values

Comment: @mahe59ab agree with using a temp variable to swap. But, how you have done using collections.swap() because when you have inbuilt function why not use it? I tried same as your question here but not working, instead a exception.